# Most efficient way to fill a typed array

Tags: javascript, performance, optimization

I have a lot of points represented by an id and their position as lat long coordinates. Every 10 seconds, a point is able to move and its position is updated. There may be 100,000 points at most but this number can also vary through time.

I need to send all this data to a user when it connects to my server.

To achieve this, I put them in a typed array like so :

```
var data = new Float32Array(points.length * 3);
for (var i = 0; i < points.length;i++) {
   data[i*3]=points[i].id;
   data[i*3+1]=points[i].position.lat;
   data[i*3+2]=points[i].position.long;
}
```

The thing is, doing this takes about 0.9 millisecond on my computer which isn't so bad but not quite satisfying. The surprising thing is that of course when lines 3,4 and 5 are commented out, the algorithm is a lot faster, but once one is not commented, it doesn't change a lot whether the two others are or not, the time will be very similar.

I would like to know if I am doing something wrong here or if there is a faster way to achieve what I want.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Is this a bottleneck, or are you prematurely optimizing?

Comment: You probably don't need the id, you can get it from the index in the TypedArray, then you can store both coords in a single float64 so that there is a single write. But if there is really one update per point every 10s, I highly doubt this is really your bottleneck.

Comment: "*when lines 3,4 and 5 are commented out, the algorithm is a lot faster*" - well empty loops that don't do anything [(can) get optimised away completely](https://mrale.ph/blog/2012/12/15/microbenchmarks-fairy-tale.html)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's about as good as it gets. Using [`.mapFlat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and [`.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/from) might make it faster but I doubt it'll be by much.

Comment: In the first place, why do you need to copy ?

Comment: Thanks for all your answers ! @Julia I am indeed prematurely optimizing, because the application I am developing is supposed to handle peaks of a thousand connections in a second, I need this to be done in less than a millisecond.

Comment: @Kaiido, thanks for your idea I might implement that.

Comment: @Bergi, I only said that because it seemed like an obvious statement, the weird thing is that from 0 to 1 write the change is big, but from 1 to 2 it is much less significant and even less when doing 3 instead of 2. And that is what I don't understand.

Comment: @Ouroborus thanks for the suggestion, I doesn't seem to make it faster for me.

Comment: @YvesDaoust What I need is not so much copying as "formatting" the data to be sent efficiently to the user.

Comment: Maybe use three typed arrays (of the appropriate types). Then you can skip the math.

Comment: @Paul I don't see what's weird about that. The loop is cheap (and a loop with an empty body even costs nothing at all, once the optimiser notices), the time is spent on the access of the `data` and `points` arrays.

Comment: I am puzzled by this. IMO, sending would be much slower than copying, so I wonder how copying could be bottleneck. And maybe is it also possible to restructure the data so that the copy is no more required.